# Fazer uma função que gera a String XML e não o XML em si PHP

Tags: php

Oi, eu estou tentando desenvolver uma função que gere somente a string do XML e não o XML.

Estou tentando conectar em um WebService que requer os seguintes requisitos:

usuario, senha, codigoAgencia e XMLRequest.

O XMLRequest são os parametros e os metodos que vou chamar no webservice

Esses 4 requisitos eu passo por soapcliente da seguinte forma:

```
array('usuarioCliente'=> $this->user,
      'senhaCliente'  => $this->password,
      'codigoAgencia' => $this->agencyCode,
      'xmlRequest' => $dados //parametros e metodos de todo o webservice
)
```

o problema é que os $dados deve ir em formato string XML, sem que apareça o 'xml version="1.0"' dentro do xmlRequest, se ele aparece o WebService reclama dos parametros e eu não estou conseguindo desenvolver uma função que transforme as chaves do PHP em STRING XML

Comment: Seria bom [edit] a pergunta e acrescentar a parte que você usa atualmente para gerar o XML, aí fica mais fácil de ajudar.

Comment: Como tem que ser a saída da string do seu XML, exatamente?

Answer (score 3):

Fazendo isso não resolve o caso?

```
function convertXML($dados)
{
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<tag_header/>');
    array_walk_recursive($dados, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
    $dados = preg_replace('/<\?xml(.*)>/', '', $xml->asXML());
    $return $dados;
}

$saida = array('usuarioCliente'=> $this->user,
      'senhaCliente'  => $this->password,
      'codigoAgencia' => $this->agencyCode,
      'xmlRequest' => convertXML($dados); 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ivan, obrigado!

Mas fiz uma função que me atende justamente pra que eu preciso,

Segue a função que desenvolvi.

```
private function toXml($array, $xml=""){
    $xml = $xml;
    foreach ($array as $chave => $valor) {
        if(is_array($valor)){
            $xml .= "<".preg_replace( '/\d+$/', null, $chave ).">".$this->toXml($valor)."</".preg_replace( '/\d+$/', null, $chave ).">";
        }
        else{
            if($chave == 'dadoAdicional1' || $chave == 'dadoAdicional2'){
                if($valor==""){
                    $xml .= "<$chave/>";
                }
                else{
                    $xml .= "<$chave>".$valor."</$chave>";
                }
            }
            else{
                if($valor==""){
                    $xml .= "<$chave/>";
                }
                else{
                    $xml .= "<".preg_replace( '/\d+$/', null, $chave ).">".$valor."</".preg_replace( '/\d+$/', null, $chave ).">";
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    return $xml;    
}
```

Fiz Um Regex para tirar os numeros das chaves e adicionei um uma exceção para campos que nao devem ser retirados os numeros.

Mesmo assim , muito obrigado por sua resposta!